# Get raw data stream from AVFoundation Capture Session

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, avfoundation

I need to get the data stream from an AVCaptureSession in a semi-live streaming type of way.  In my experience with AVFoundation, I can only write the file to disk and then read it out.

Is there a way to capture the data as it comes through the stream to pipe out to a server?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to send raw PCM then you can get all the data out of the CMSampledBuffer. Take a look at the CMSampleBuffer.h and the CMSampleBuffer reference for how to get at the data. If you want to stream AAC then you will need to use CoreAudio. You can do this using the simple AudioQueue services. If you need more control, such as using AAC-LD or audio cancellation, then you will need to use AudioUnits. Check out the CoreAudio book from Kevin Avila and Chris Adamson. I used the AudioQueue recording code as a test case for streaming AAC audio to a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the raw data using [`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and/or [`AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureAudioDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: How do you take CMSampleBuffer objects and turn them into NSData objects suitable to be sent to the server?

Comment: @Dex: Depends on the format you are capturing. In general you get the image buffer and lock it as shown [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_MediaRepresentations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH2-SW4). Then you can collect the raw data by using the `CVPixelBuffer` functions to retrieve all planes.

Comment: I'm actually recording Audio only

Comment: @Dex: Use `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` in that case.

Comment: I still need to get the data out of the CMSampleBuffer on that delegate callback.  I'm trying to send this data live to the server.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Dex: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598934/how-to-play-audio-sample-buffers-from-avcaptureaudiodataoutput) for example code.