# Is it possible to do some sound analysis on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I am enrolled in a course about phonetic analysis and it demands a final project. I am wondering if I can do this on iOS. I know that there is a way to record, but is there a way to get the waveform or something that could be analyzed from that recording?

Comment: I'd add, however, that for a "final project" coding to iPhone may not be a wise idea (unless you already know the platform well).  You will spend a fair amount of time fighting the OS and interfaces and tools, and will almost certainly be stymied numerous times.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for the advise. I have no idea what platform to work on, but I intend to learn about iOS. What I want is to do record a person's voice(this seems easier) and do some analysis. Do you think these will take a lot of time? By the way, I'm really sorry that I didn't take your answer because the accepted answer is a little bit earlier.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "a lot of time".  I've been working on this app for about a year, off and on, and someone else before me.  But it's complicated, and the algorithms have to be invented.  Plus there are separate UI issues.  But simple recording is fairly straight-forward, and then you can read the file and analyze the resulting fairly "normally", using C facilities, without too many iOS oddities.  But budget at least a month full-time to come up to speed with iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can open the recording or audio file and access its sample data. APIs for reading the file and its sample data exist. Accelerate.framework can convert your signal from the time domain to the frequency domain. However, iOS frameworks do not include particularly featured APIs for your common signal analyses, so you will need to write the majority of what you need for your analysis algorithms.

Comment: I agree with @waggles, a few days ago Novocaine was released: http://alexbw.github.com/novocaine/ I really recommend to take a look at it, it makes tasks like sound analysis a lot easier! (instead of rolling your own)

Comment: Heya, I'm the maker of Novocaine, and just to pitch in on the situation: Novocaine makes acquiring and playing audio pretty easy, but I realize that what to actually _do_ with your audio once you have it is still a difficult problem. I'm working on another companion library with a friend which makes analysis and synthesis a lot easier. Probably a half-year off (I'm still a student, so it takes a bit of time to get these things done correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can do lots of things to analyze sound in iOS.  I'm currently working on a project that does a real-time [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) to analyze sound.

There aren't (or at least weren't, prior to Siri or whatever it is) built-in facilities in iOS to do a lot of the sound processing, but there are plenty of 3rd-party C-language freeware utilities on the web which can be compiled to run on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the [AVCaptureAudioDataOutput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureAudioDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

This question may help also: [How to play audio sample buffers from AVCaptureAudioDataOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598934/how-to-play-audio-sample-buffers-from-avcaptureaudiodataoutput)